# Autodisk forge files

Tags: autodesk-forge

I was wondering, the dwg files are hosted on my server, to use the viewer API do I need to upload it to forge platform then I can use the viewer API?
if yes is there API  or otherways to upload the files to the platform I do not want to do it manually
if no this means it's ok I can use the viewer on the files on my server

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to show any model (other than **PDF**) in the **Viewer**, you need to get it translated to **SVF**, which is the **Viewer**'s format. This translation can only be done on our servers, so the file needs to be there at least while the translation is running.
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/showing-files-viewer

We have a nice tutorial on how this can be done: https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewmodels

Comment: thank you so much, I did test it with the react project and it is working as you explained